# unity2D Moving to a fixed object causes weightlessness

Tags: unity-game-engine

Please look at the [photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGoUd.gif). There are two objects.

```
left circle object = circle colider2D + rigidbody2D(freeze Rotation Z, script for move )

    Rigidbody2D rigid;
    float moveX;

    void Start()
    {
       rigid = gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }


    void PlayerMove(){
        moveX = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        rigid.velocity = new Vector2(moveX * 5f, rigid.velocity.y);
    }

    void Update(){
        PlayerMove();
    }

right square object = square colider2D + rigidbody2D(freeze positionY, freeze positionX, freeze Rotation Z)
```

I can move the circle from side to side.
While I press the keyboard and push the circle to the right wall, gravity doesn't work.

I don't know why. I hope gravity will work even if the circle hit the wall.

How can I prevent the problem?

Comment: Check [physic materials](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PhysicMaterial.html) :)

Answer (score 3):

Looks like physics material that's applied to that rigidbody has too much friction and slows down too much when hugging the wall. Try reducing friction value on the material (you can create the physics2D material from the assets panel).

[image: Rigidbody setup]

[image: Material setup]

Comment: @홍우기 If you think that answered the question, you should accept the answer